# How to programmatically deploy static html pages to heroku?

Tags: java, git, heroku, jgit

**Problem:** 
I want to host static html pages (+ some imgs), but have them be uploaded to the host programmatically.

**Current Solution:**
I use github to store my html pages, and push my files to a remote repository using an API called jGit. I can view my website using an online tool that displays html sites from github's raw source code. People told me this is abusing github so I want to move away from doing this.

So I heard about Heroku. Is it possible to upload my files to heroku using jGit? Are there any limitations to this? Are there better/easier alternatives?

Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is to run your server, If you are just looking for static HTML hosting, explore GitHub Pages/ S3/ netlify

I would recommend GitHub Pages as you are already using GitHub.

Comment: Github pages is super easy to use, and it seems like something Kyrix would use. Also, if you want to link a 'real URL', that can be done by just buying a domain name and linking it to your Github pages!

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. If I have two files (in two different local repostories) on two different computers, that I want to push to ONE remote repository (my github pages page), how would this be done. I know this has to do with cloning or pulling, but I am not sure as my knowledge of git is limited.